# ¿how to enable or disable the following indicator in one click?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I would like this indicator to have the option to turn it on and off, but unfortunately, I don't know how to do it the right way.

```
//@version=5
    indicator(title='XTL,EMAS,VWAP,IMBALANCE sin Pivot v5', shorttitle='indicador definitivo V5', overlay=true)
    
    len = input.int(34, minval=1, title='XTL Period', group="XTL indicator")
    hLmt = input.int(34, title='Threshold Value', group="XTL indicator", minval=10)
    
    xtl_src = hlc3
    XTL = ta.cci(xtl_src, len)
        
    bull = XTL > hLmt
    bear = XTL < -hLmt
    neutral = XTL <= hLmt and XTL >= -hLmt
    
    upcolor = color.rgb(0, 135, 225)
    dwncolor = color.rgb(255, 0, 0)
    ntlcolor = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 30)
    
    bcol = bull ? upcolor : neutral ? ntlcolor : dwncolor
    hcol = close > open ? na : bcol
    plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=hcol, wickcolor=bcol, bordercolor=bcol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it with Pinescript though

```
//@version=5
    indicator(title='XTL,EMAS,VWAP,IMBALANCE sin Pivot v5', shorttitle='indicador definitivo V5', overlay=true)
    
    show = input.bool(true)
    len = input.int(34, minval=1, title='XTL Period', group="XTL indicator")
    hLmt = input.int(34, title='Threshold Value', group="XTL indicator", minval=10)
    
    xtl_src = hlc3
    XTL = ta.cci(xtl_src, len)
        
    bull = XTL > hLmt
    bear = XTL < -hLmt
    neutral = XTL <= hLmt and XTL >= -hLmt
    
    upcolor = color.rgb(0, 135, 225)
    dwncolor = color.rgb(255, 0, 0)
    ntlcolor = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 30)
    
    bcol = bull ? upcolor : neutral ? ntlcolor : dwncolor
    hcol = close > open ? na : bcol
    plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=show ? hcol : na, wickcolor=show ? bcol : na, bordercolor=show ? bcol : na)
```